# Automate the process of comparing the values of 2 csv files if value matches read the second csv into the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have imported an excel into a dataframe. It looks like this:

[image]

Then I used a code to groupby this data as per 'tx_id' and create separate csv with the name of tx_id which gives me data like this (3e6737ae-c3af-4d19-a645-d17fc73dbb7c.csv). This is the code:

```
for i, g in dframe.groupby('tx_id'):
     g.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(i.split('/')[0]), index=False)
```

Then I created a separate dframe containing only the tx_id and then dropped the duplicates using this code:

```
dframe1 = dframe1.drop_duplicates()
```

Now my dataframe looks like this:

[image]

I have converted this dataframe into csv. Now I want to compare the names of the csv file(which is the tx_id value) with the data present in the newly created csv and if the names match , I would like to read the csv file(which is the tx_id value) into the dataframe. I used to import these csv files manually but I have a large dataset , it's not feasible for me to read the data each time and do further process on it. Right now what I am doing is importing the csv files individually into a dataframe. I am using this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(' ae229a81-bb33-4cf1-ba2f-360fffb0d94b.csv')
```

This gives me the result like:

[image]

Then I used to unstack it and apply value_counts by using this code:

```
df1 = df.groupby('rule_id')['request_id'].value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)
```

And the end result used to look like this:

[image]

I want to automate this process and I don't know how. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate your `tx_id` and append the dataframes to `list`:

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = []
for tx in dframe1['tx_id']:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv('%s.csv' % tx))
```

This only works if it's executed in the same directory as the csv files. Otherwise:

```
import os
import pandas

dfs = []

for tx in dframe1['tx_id']:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(os.path.join('/path/to/csv/', '%s.csv' % tx)))
```

Editted

Instead of appending dataframe directly, if you want to apply some functions:

```
for tx in dframe1['tx_id']:
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join('/path/to/csv/', '%s.csv' % tx))
    dfs.append(df.groupby('rule_id')['request_id'].value_counts().unstack().fillna(0))
```

Now your `dfs` has all the `value_counts()` results. You can refer them using indices.

If you want to find them using the filename, use `dict`:

```
df_dict = dict()
for tx in dframe1['tx_id']:
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join('/path/to/csv/', '%s.csv' % tx))
    df_dict[tx] = df.groupby('rule_id')['request_id'].value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)
```

Comment: This is working @Chris. But can I have these in separate dataframes , like creating a separate dataframe for each grouped by tx_id.

Comment: @sagarkhanna I'm not sure what you mean by in separate dataframes. `dfs` contains separate dataframes. Do you want to access the dataframes by their names?

Comment: Yes. Earlier what I used to do is , I used to import the csv as df = pd.read_csv('csv_name.csv') and then I have to unstack it and use value_counts on it. I will edit my question and add what I need the result to look like.

Comment: @sagarkhanna I think its better if you post what you want to do and thus get from each dataframe in terms of code you would have applied individually.

Comment: I have applied your code @Chris but I am getting the error that 'list indices must be integers , not str'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189081/discussion-between-chris-and-sagar-khanna).

Comment: Hi @Chris , can you help me with something else? I have updated your code to my requirements but I am stuck at a certain place. I will edit the question so that you can get the clear idea what my problem is.

Comment: @sagarkhanna Its not really recommended to change the question that already has an answer for the future references. You can make a new post and leave a link here :)

Comment: Ok sure. @Chris

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54903887/automate-the-process-of-dropping-similar-looking-columns-and-then-transposing-th

Comment: I have added the link in the comment.