# Automate the process of dropping similar looking columns and then transposing the data in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a code which contains multiple columns and I want to drop certain columns and then transpose the remaining data. Earlier I used to do it manually but I have a large dataset so it won't be possible for me to do it manually. This is the data and these type of columns I want to drop(will highlight them):

[image]

After dropping the highlighted columns , I want the transpose of rule_id(I have converted rule_id into index) , and 'comp' columns and then convert this data into a dataframe. Can I automate this process? If yes , then how. This is the code I am using:

```
    dfs = []
for tx in dframe2['tx_id']:
    df = pd.read_csv('%s.csv' % tx)
    df1 = df.groupby('rule_id')['request_id'].value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)
    #dfs.append(df1)
    m = df1.eq(df1.shift(-1, axis=1))

    arr1 = np.select([df1 ==0, m], [np.nan, df1], df1*100)

    dft4 = pd.DataFrame(arr1, index=df1.index).rename(columns=lambda x: 'comp{}'.format(x+1))

    dft5 = df1.join(dft4)
    #dfs.append(dft5)
    cols = [c for c in dft5.columns if '-' in c]
    df8 = dft5.drop(cols, axis=1)
    df9 = df8.transpose()
    #print(df9)
    dfs.append(df9)
```

The end result should look like this:

[image]

This is kind of a followup question to [Automate the process of comparing the values of 2 csv files if value matches read the second csv into the DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54887451/automate-the-process-of-comparing-the-values-of-2-csv-files-if-value-matches-rea/54887679?noredirect=1#comment96574313_54887679)

After applying your code @Frenchy , I am getting this result:

[image]

But I want all the rule_id in one row at the top , followed by comp values as shown here:

[image]

Comment: in your code you have request_id? what is the structure of your column after reading csv file?

Comment: The request_id are the columns which I have highlighted @Frenchy. I am including a link to a question which I asked previously , it contains the structure of csv file.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54887451/automate-the-process-of-comparing-the-values-of-2-csv-files-if-value-matches-rea/54887679?noredirect=1#comment96574313_54887679

Comment: ok..you want to drop all columns with contains the type of name you indicate?

Comment: Yes and then transpose the remaining columns and convert the data into dataframe which looks like the picture I added as a result. I am able to transpose it but I am facing problem in dropping and converting it into the desired layout.

Comment: Did you just delete your result? @Frenchy

Comment: no just do a mistake....i undelete it

Comment: not clear, if i understand you have more row with the rule_id in the csv file or you have one dataframe different for each file you want to join?

Comment: you have a list of dataframe so? and your rule id are uniques?

Comment: I want to concatenate the rule_id row @Frenchy. For eg , In the question ,  result which I am getting is rule_id 51567 51574 , then there are its comp values , the there is next rule_id 50014 50469 ....etc. I want to join them to get result like rule_id 51567 51574 50014 50469 and so on. I want the list to be dataframe and look like the image I attached in the end.

Comment: so in your code,  before your transpose, you should do df8.set_index('rule_id', inplace=True)

Comment: I am getting an error. I am taking this to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189133/discussion-between-sagar-khanna-and-frenchy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a sample of solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'rule_id': [50014, 50238, 53139],
              'comp1': [100, np.nan, 100],
               '0f1410-0440-0123':[0,1,2],
              'comp2': [np.nan,np.nan, np.nan],
              'd10-0440-0123':[0,1,2],
              'comp3': [np.nan,100, np.nan]})

print(df)

#delete columns which contains '-' in name
cols = [c for c in df.columns if '-' in c]
df.drop(cols, axis=1, inplace=True)

df.set_index('rule_id', inplace=True)
df = df.transpose()
print(df)
```

Initial DF:

```
  rule_id  comp1  0f1410-0440-0123  comp2  d10-0440-0123  comp3
0    50014  100.0                 0    NaN              0    NaN
1    50238    NaN                 1    NaN              1  100.0
2    53139  100.0                 2    NaN              2    NaN
```

Final DF:

```
rule_id  50014  50238  53139
comp1    100.0    NaN  100.0
comp2      NaN    NaN    NaN
comp3      NaN  100.0    NaN
```

hope that help!!

for second question,group all DFs

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'rule_id': [50014, 50238, 53139],
          'comp1': [100, 100, 100],
          'comp2': [100,100, 100],
          'comp3': [1.0,1.0, 1.0]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'rule_id': [50028, 50258, 53339],
          'comp1': [1.0, 1.0, 100],
          'comp2': [100,np.nan, 100]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'rule_id': [50030, 50259, 53340, 53342],
          'comp1': [1.0, 1.0, 100, 200],
          'comp2': [100,100, 100, 200],
          'comp3': [100,100, 100, 200],
          'comp4': [1.0,np.nan, 1.0, np.nan]})

df1.set_index('rule_id', inplace=True)
df1 = df1.transpose()
df2.set_index('rule_id', inplace=True)
df2 = df2.transpose()
df3.set_index('rule_id', inplace=True)
df3 = df3.transpose()

listofdftransposed = [df1,df2,df3] #-> list of df as my result of extend job
df_result = pd.concat(listofdftransposed)
print(df_result)
```

output:

```
rule_id  50014  50028  50030  50238  50258  50259  53139  53339  53340  53342
comp1    100.0    NaN    NaN  100.0    NaN    NaN  100.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
comp2    100.0    NaN    NaN  100.0    NaN    NaN  100.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
comp3      1.0    NaN    NaN    1.0    NaN    NaN    1.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
comp1      NaN    1.0    NaN    NaN    1.0    NaN    NaN  100.0    NaN    NaN
comp2      NaN  100.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  100.0    NaN    NaN
comp1      NaN    NaN    1.0    NaN    NaN    1.0    NaN    NaN  100.0  200.0
comp2      NaN    NaN  100.0    NaN    NaN  100.0    NaN    NaN  100.0  200.0
comp3      NaN    NaN  100.0    NaN    NaN  100.0    NaN    NaN  100.0  200.0
comp4      NaN    NaN    1.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    1.0    NaN
```

Comment: This solves my problem to an extent @Frenchy. I am getting the data in grouped by format. For eg, I am getting the rule_id , then the compare columns , but I want the result as mentioned in the question. I will edit the question and add the result I am getting for your reference.

Comment: So the objective is to concatenate all these 3 dataframes into one. Like df = pd.concat([df1 , df2 , df3]) So that the result look like the last image of the question

Comment: I have a list @Frenchy. I don't have a dataframe. I won't be able to use pd.concat on the list. I will edit the question and edit my code too. So that you can have a clear idea what my code looks like.

Comment: Take a look at the code I just edited in my question.@Frenchy

Comment: so dfs is the list of dataframes transposed?

Comment: Yes. Now I don't know how to concatenate the values in this list so that all the rule_id come in one row.

Comment: after the loop, you have try  to do: dfs_result = pd.concat(dfs)??